# does this book contradict itself on procedure overloading

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
TYPE DateTyp IS TABLE OF DATE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
TYPE NumTyp IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
hiredate DateTyp;
sal NumTyp;
PROCEDURE initial(tab OUT DateTyp, n INTEGER) IS
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
tab(i) := SYSDATE;
END LOOP;
END initial;
PROCEDURE initial(tab OUT NumTyp, n INTEGER) IS
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
tab(i) := 0.0;
END LOOP;
END initial;
BEGIN
Initial(hiredate, 50);  --calls first(DateTyp) version
initial(sal, 100);  --calls second(NumTyp) version
END;
```

they give this example (which they say is valid) to show subprogram overloading..."They differ only in their parameter types."

but then they give this restriction guideline:

```
You cannot overload two subprograms that differ only in their subtypes. For example, you cannot overload the following two subprograms:

DECLARE
...
PROCEDURE withdraw(amount INTEGER) IS
BEGIN ... END;
PROCEDURE withdraw(amount REAL) IS
BEGIN ... END;
```

what am i not seeing or understanding....they're giving an example by only changing the parameter type, which they say is valid (first example)....then they say it's not allowed

the first example only change tab from DateTyp to NumTyp....then the 2nd example only changes amount from INTEGER to REAL...

Comment: Which book is this from?  The first example looks ropey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two examples are not contradictory. DateType is a TABLE OF DATE; NumTyp is a TABLE OF NUMBER. These are distinctly different types. INTEGER and REAL are both subtypes of NUMBER, and are defined in the STANDARD package as:

```
type NUMBER is NUMBER_BASE;
 subtype FLOAT is NUMBER; -- NUMBER(126)
 subtype REAL is FLOAT; -- FLOAT(63)
 subtype "DOUBLE PRECISION" is FLOAT;
 subtype INTEGER is NUMBER(38,0);
```

So INTEGER is a direct subtype of NUMBER, and REAL is a subtype of FLOAT which is a subtype of NUMBER. Thus, INTEGER and REAL are both subtypes of NUMBER, and thus can't be used as the only difference between overloaded subprograms.

Comment: yeah...i just learned that they were subtypes of number...good call...a bit tricky of an example though...but yeah

Answer (score 1):

The PL/SQL documentation has a useful appendix which I think helps explain the difference.  [Find it here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/predefined.htm#LNPLS2163).

It divides supported datatypes into families.  DATE, NUMBER and VARCHAR2 are different families.  Overloaded procedures which have arguments of different datatype families (e.g. DATE and VARCHAR2) are distinct and therefore permitted.     Overloaded procedures which have arguments from the same datatype family (REAL and INTEGER) are not distinct, because they are both of type NUMBER.  Hence they are not permitted.

Basically, which instance of the second procedure does this call reference?

```
withdraw(200);
```

Nobody can tell.